# Multiply column values by itself using awk

Tags: command

I would like to multiply column values by itself using `awk`. How can I do that?

example

```
1  5 1
2  6 0 
3  7 3
4  8 5
```

output

```
1X5X1 =5                  1  5 1 5
X X X
2X6X0 =0      ===>        2  6 0 0
X X X
3X7X3 =63                 3  7 3 63
X X X
4X8X5 =160                4  8 5 160
| | |                     | | |
V V V                     V V V          
24 1680 0                 24 1680 0
```

I know how to sum the values using `awk` but how I can multiply it?

```
awk '{sum2+=$2;  ... etc} END {print sum2,... etc}'
```

Comment: The output in the fourth line of your fourth column should be `160` and not `1600`.

Comment: please help this is very important  i don't know how to do it  ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the number of columns in advance:

```
BEGIN { p1 = p2 = p3 = 1 }
{ p1 *= $1; p2 *= $2; p3 *= $3; print $0, $1 * $2 * $3 }
END { print p1, p2, p3 }
```

This should handle files where any row can have any number of columns:

```
{
        for(i = p = 1; i <= NF; i++){
                s[i] = s[i] == "" ? $i : s[i] * $i; p *= $i
        }
        print $0, ":", p
        if(NF > mf) mf = NF
}
END {
        ORS="";
        for(i = 1; i < mf; i++) print s[i] FS;
        print s[i] RS
}
```

In this case, the product of fields from a line is appended to the line following a ":", in order to distinguish it from a normal field.

Comment: Thank you sir. I appreciate if you explain it? why can't be simple like the sum of columns? please how can I list the original table and the results of multiplication of rows and columns like in my example? please help?

Comment: because undefined variables in awk have the default numeric value of 0, which is the identity element for addition, but not for multiplication ;-)

Comment: Thank you sir. you are genius!  just I have one problem the rows give extra ": " like "1  5 1 : 5" how can I remove it?

Comment: i don't have reputations to give thumb up sorry

Comment: You can remove the `, ":"` from `print ...` if all your rows have the same number of columns.